# How do I get the fullname of a file in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air, flash-cs3

I'm using something like this to browse for a file in AIR. I can get the filename, but what I need is the fullname of the file. Is there a way to do that?

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference(); 
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler); 
file.browse();

private function selectHandler(e:Event):void{ 
file.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler); 
var name = file.name; 
}
```

Comment: I'm using Flash CS3, by the way, as you can see in my tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `FileReference` can give you the absolute path of the file you selected. So I suggest you to use `nativePath` property of the `File` rather than `FileReference`.

```
var file:File = File.userDirectory;
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
file.browse();

private function selectHandler(e:Event):void{
file.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
var filePath:String= file.nativePath;
}
```

Comment: dang, I was using wrong class. using File instead of FileReference will do.
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flex Builder? I'd put a break in the handler and see what is available. the "name" property is proper for getting the filename as it is on disk though, so I don't know what the problem is in your situation.

Comment: name just gives me the filename and other properties, but not the full native path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no air expert, but how about file.nativePath ?

Comment: the FileReference class doesn't have nativePath property.