# Getting the path of an uploaded file in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6

How can we get absolute path of file or "native Path" of file (as we call it in Flex/AIR) when we use File Reference to browse a file in adobe flash builder 4.6?

For example,if i uploaded a image from : "c:\upload\check.jpeg"
I want the full path.. as "c:\upload\check.jpeg".

I need this in adobe flash builder 4.6,actually i Googled it but i got some outdated code i.e in flex 4.3 ([How do I get the fullname of a file in Adobe AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903080/how-do-i-get-the-fullname-of-a-file-in-adobe-air))
which is not working in 4.6

If any one knows,please help me i will be very thankful for them

Answer (score 0):

```
In Flash builder we cannot get the native path due to security concerned Adobe systems does't gave 
option to get the native path in web applications but we can get native path in AIR applications..
After  searching  many hours in Internet finally i came to know about that..
```